# Haskell combine multiple typeclass constraints

Tags: haskell, type-families

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Prim
import qualified Data.Set as Set

class Functor' f where
    type FConstraint f :: * -> Constraint
    fmap' :: (FConstraint f a, FConstraint f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Functor' Set.Set where
    type FConstraint Set.Set = Ord Num  --error here, won't let me put Num
    fmap' = Set.map
```

I was wondering how I could make the above work. Now I know I could manually require two typeclasses, but I was hoping to be able to combine any arbitrary amount of them.

Now I know requiring `Num` does not make sense in this case, but this is purely an example.

Comment: The problem is that `Ord` is a class and `Num` is a class too. So `Ord Num` is a malformed constraint. It should be something like `Ord type` and `Num type` if you want to constrain `type` with both `Ord` and `Num`.

Comment: @Bakuriu I get what you are saying, and I didn't expect `Ord Num` to work as is, but I tried variations of that like `(Ord a, Num a) => a` and couldn't get any of them working, I am gonna try some more stuff today and see if I can find a working one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the only change I needed to make was not partially apply `FConstraint`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Prim
import qualified Data.Set as Set

class Functor' f where
    type FConstraint f a :: Constraint
    fmap' :: (FConstraint f a, FConstraint f b) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b 

instance Functor' Set.Set where
    type FConstraint Set.Set a = (Ord a, Num a)
    fmap' f = Set.map ((+ 1) . f)

foo = fmap (+ 1) $ Set.fromList [1, 2, 3]
```

Unfortunately this does not allow me to use a concrete type as far as I can tell, but I suppose that wouldn't even match with Functor on a kind level anyway (`Functor` has kind `* -> *` but a list of concrete values such as `String` has kind `*`).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to define a typeclass (since typeclasses can be partially applied ) which reduces to the constraint you want through a superclass:

```
{-# LANGUAGE 
    PolyKinds, UndecidableInstances, TypeOperators
  , MultiParamTypeClasses, ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies
  , FlexibleContexts, FlexibleInstances 
#-}

class (f x, g x) => (&) f g (x :: k)
instance (f x, g x) => (&) f g x
```

Clearly `(f & g) x` holds iff `f x` and `g x` hold. The definition of `FConstraint'` should be obvious now:

```
class Functor' ... 

instance Functor' Set.Set where
    type FConstraint Set.Set = Ord & Num
    fmap' f = Set.map ( (+1) . f )  -- (+1) to actually use the Num constraint
```

Comment: I tried copying what you wrote but I ended up needing to turn on a LOT of extensions: `{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, FlexibleContexts, MultiParamTypeClasses, PolyKinds, TypeFamilies, TypeOperators, UndecidableInstances #-}` and even then it still told me `No instance for ((&) Ord Num b0) arising from a use of ‘fmap'’ In the expression: fmap' (+ 1)`.

Comment: @semicolon I accidentally a line. Should be fixed now.

Comment: I am now getting `Illegal instance declaration for ‘(&) f g x’ (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*, and each type variable appears at most once`